# Getting a promise back from an Angular Resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I'm using $resource to do some basic CRUD stuff in Angular but I don't think I understand how to use the different resource methods.

As far as I can tell, the "regular" methods - `save()`, `get()` etc happen synchronously, and you can pass in a callback function to run on completion if you want to do "classic" JS async calls. The result of each also has a `$promise` property which returns a promise, if you want to do async that way (I do!).

But there are also `$` versions of all the methods except (for reasons I also don't understand) `get()` and `query()`. Are these `$` methods a shortcut for `.$promise`? If so, why is there no `$get()` or `$query()`?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628787/difference-between-save-and-save-to-resource-in-angularjs

Comment: That answers some of it, thanks. But it doesn't answer which methods return values or promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the docs of ngResource are very hard to understand.
Basically you need to differentiate between

- class actions (methods of $resource) and
- instance actions (methods of instances of $resource)

class actions like

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

have an additional property `$promise` that is resolved when the data is returned from the `$http` request. Thats why this can be written as:

```
User.get({userId:123})
    .$promise.then(function(user) {
      $scope.user = user;
    });
```

from the docs:

> When the data is returned from the server then the object is an
>   instance of the resource class. The actions save, remove and delete
>   are available on it as methods with the $ prefix. This allows you to
>   easily perform CRUD operations (create, read, update, delete) on
>   server-side data like this:

That's why `user.$save();` can be invoked on the instance in the example above.

Comment: So do all the class actions have the `$promise` property?

Comment: At least it seems so. The Docs say 'Class actions return empty instance (with the $promise property)'